# Different results when writing to binary file using std::ofstream

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ubuntu, window

When writing to binary file using `std::ofstream`, the results are different on Windows and Linux although they are both little endian

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

template<class T>
void Write(std::ofstream& os, T i)
{
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(T));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::ofstream geofile;
    std::string geofilename = "out.bin";
    geofile.open(geofilename.c_str());

    int v = 10;
    Write(geofile, v);

    if (geofile.is_open()) geofile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

On Ubuntu, the code produce "0a00 0000" and on Windows is "0d0a 0000 00". Why there is such difference and how to make them the same?

Comment: On windows line endings are `"\r\n"`, not solely `"\n"`

Comment: Try opening as binary.

Comment: `geofile.open(geofilename.c_str());` -> `geofile.open(geofilename);`. If it doesnt compile you should get a more uptodate compiler

Comment: Try using `std::ofstream.write()`, e.g. `geofile.write(&v, sizeof(int));`

Comment: Open as binary `geofile.open(geofilename.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);`

Comment: Recommendation: test the stream state after writing to make sure the write succeeded. Sucks to `write` the data to a file and then find out that you actually didn't.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the code does far too elaborate a dance to open the file. `std::ofstream geofile("out.bin");` does the same thing. Also, there's no need to call `geofile.close();`; the destructor will do that.

Comment: Files can be opened in **text** mode or in **binary** mode. The default is text mode, and that means that the runtime will encode the file according to the text conventions of the target platform, even when you call `os.write`. To write binary data, open the file in binary mode.

Comment: I  am able   to   read data 0A00 0000  using  std::ios::binary  on Windows.

Comment: Did the answer below work? Are there any new problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line breaks on Windows are `\r\n` (`0D 0A`), but are either `\r` (`0D`) or `\n` (`0A`) on other platforms.  C++ file streams operate in `text` mode by default, so they will perform line break conversions at runtime, converting `\n` to platform-native line breaks on writes, and normalizing platform-native line breaks to `\n` on reads.

As you can see in your example, on Windows the byte `0A` is being converted to bytes `0D 0A`, but on Ubuntu no conversion is made since `\n` is already the native line break.

To get the same result on all platforms, you need to open the file in `binary` mode to disable line break conversions, eg:

```
std::ofstream geofile;
geofile.open("out.bin", std::ios::binary);
```

Or:

```
std::ofstream geofile("out.bin", std::ios::binary);
```